# Lodash's shortcut fusion with lazy evaluation doesn't optimize

Tags: javascript, performance, lodash, lazy-evaluation

I'm trying to test Lodash's [lazy evaluation and shortcut fusion](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#lodash) but it seems like the shortcut fusion works for very limited cases.

For example, I'd expect the following to be performant and should've looped over the array only once/twice, but the case doesn't seems so:

```js
_([...Array(10000000)])
.fill(100)
.filter(i => i)
.filter(i => i)
.filter(i => i)
.filter(i => i)
.filter(i => i)
.filter(i => i)
.filter(i => i)
.value();
```

The native chaining as follows is taking similar compute time:

```js
[...Array(10000000)]
.fill(100)
.filter(i => i)
.filter(i => i)
.filter(i => i)
.filter(i => i)
.filter(i => i)
.filter(i => i)
.filter(i => i)
```

Ideally, I'd have expected lodash to simply merge all the subsequent filters into a single logically **And*ed*** operation and hence a single loop.
Am I doing anything wrong or expecting a lot out of their so-called ***heuristic*** ?

Here is a perf test link: https://jsbench.me/dukl7k4rhc/1

Comment: What browser did you test this on? What were your results?

Comment: If you AND all these filters you end up with basically the same operation. Instead of `if (i) { if (i) { /* etc */} }` you get `if (i && i /* etc */)` which will check `i` the same amount of times. You seem to be asking for lodash to realise all predicates are the same and eliminate them but that's not what it does.